# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

what do i do, with this error in codeigniter?

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'show' at line 1
>
> SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r,
>   hotel_submits t order by id desc LIMIT 2, show
>
> Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\mehdi\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

code:

```
$data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, hotel_submits t order by id desc LIMIT ".$config['per_page'].", ".$this->uri->segment(3)."");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the Codeigniter Pagination class properly.

See my answer to your other question: [create jquery pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056223/create-jquery-pagination)

Your `$config['base_url']` needs your controller and method names, like so:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'controllerName/show';
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->uri->segment(3)` is returning the string `show`, wich is not a valid `LIMIT` value.

I suppose you're calling the wrong segment.