# problem count rows on table in pagination?

Tags: php, codeigniter, count, pagination

I use of codeigniter

I have an problem with `rownum` in following code. it is this that, in `each page of pagination` rows in table `be counted from the beginning`. For **example**, the clear:

**P1:** If we're on the **first page of pagination**, rows are the counts:

```
1 Columns1
2 Columns2
3 Columns3
4 Columns4
```

**P2:** If we're on the **second page of pagination**, rows are the counts:

```
1 Columns5
2 Columns6
3 Columns7
4 Columns8
```

**P2:** The I want to be counted row in table,(on the **second page** of pagination and ...):

```
5 Columns5
6 Columns6
7 Columns7
8 Columns8
```

**P3:** ... and more

This code:

```
$data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* ".
        "FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, hotel_submits t ".
        "ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $offset, 4");
```

Full code:

```
function show($offset = 0) 
    {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/accommodation/show';
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('hotel_submits');
        $config['per_page'] = '4';          

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);    
            $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();                                        

        $offset = (int) $offset; // just to make sure nothing funky gets in here
        $data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* ".
            "FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, hotel_submits t ".
            "ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $offset, 4");

            ////////////////////////                                

            $this->load->view('admin/accommodation_submit_show', $data); 
}
```

How is it?

With respect

**Editing and more about this:**

I do not want that in each page of pagination, rows are counted from the beginning.
The next page will be counted on every prev page.

see this images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

my view:

```
   <div class="table_show">
    <table>
        <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="true" ></th>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>نوع</th>
                <th>نام</th>
                <th>ستاره - نوع</th>
                <th>آدرس</th>
                <th>شماره تماس</th>
                <th>نمابر</th>
                <th>وب سایت</th>
                <th>ایمیل</th>
                <th>زمان ثبت</th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    //echo $this->table->generate($results);    
        foreach ($results->result() as $row)
        {
                echo    '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" value="true" ></td>';
                echo    '<td>'.$row->rownum.'</td>';
                echo    '<td>'.$row->type.'</td>';
                echo    '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
                echo    '<td>'.$row->star.' - '.$row->type_star.'</td>';                                
                echo    '<td><span id="'.$row->address.'" class="tooltip">'.$row->address.'</span></td>';
                echo    '<td><span id="'.$row->number_phone.'" class="tooltip">'.$row->number_phone.'</span></td>';
                echo    '<td>'.$row->fax.'</td>';
                echo    '<td>'.$row->site.'</td>';
                echo    '<td>'.$row->email.'</td>';
                echo    '<td>'.$row->date.'</td></tr>';
            }
    ?>

    </table>
    <?= $pagination;?>
</div>
```

Comment: I've been chasing you around with your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056223/create-jquery-pagination/7057591#7057591, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057596/a-database-error-occurred-error-number-1064/7057643#7057643, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057829/problem-with-pagination/7057855#7057855, and more. Why do you keep on opening new threads?

Comment: @Joseph Silber - Thank you for your reply, The problems are different from each other.Your comments,long question seems that putting in comments?

Comment: If the other answers were resolved, then accept my answer by click on the check-mark next to the question. You're still not passing in the $offset. See my answer...

Comment: You accepted the answer to one question, but not to the others. Stack Overflow is specifically designed so that other people searching for the same question should easily find the answer. If the other answers answered your questions, you should accept them too...

Comment: Consider making one question per thread. If a problem depends on another, do it in order.

Comment: @Alfonso Rubalcava - Please see only to problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems:

1) You're not passing in the offset.

2) You're not telling the Pagination class which URI segment to use.

```
function show($offset = 0) // You need the offset
{
    // load pagination class
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/accommodation/show';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('hotel_submits');
    $config['per_page'] = '2';
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4; // You have to tell CI which URI segment to use

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $offset = (int) $offset; // just to make sure nothing funky gets in here
    $data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* ".
    "FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, hotel_submits t ".
    "ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $offset, 2");

    $this->load->view('admin/accommodation_submit_show', $data);   
}
```

**EDIT:**

Now that your code works well, we can address your problem (I'm assuming you're using MySQL):

You're trying to use `@rownum` to get the row numbers, but `@rownum` is not supported in MySQL.

However, there's a workaround (idea taken from [here](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/09/13/rownum-simulation-with-mysql/)). Change your query to:

```
$data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.*
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM hotel_submits
        ORDER BY id desc
        LIMIT $offset, 2    
    ) t,
    (SELECT @rownum:=0) r");
```

Comment: Sorry, I putting my old code, I update the post. I have a new problem(in rownum), What is the solution?

Comment: Are you using `"ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $offset, 2");`, or `"ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $offset, 4");`? Please proofread before you post!!!

Comment: Was performed. what do i do with new problem(in `rownum`)?

Comment: **What do i do? Please help me**

Comment: What is your problem? You have not mentioned what your problem is! You are getting your query back the way you want it, and sending it off to the view. So far so good. Now it seems you have some sort of issue in your view, but you have not posted anything regarding your view, and I have no way of knowing what you're trying to do there!!!

Comment: Can you also post the relevant PHP from your view that generates this table?

Comment: Ok, I putting it. please see post.?

Comment: @Joseph: I feel your pain. You are a trooper.

Comment: @Wesley: Thanks man! You have no idea what that comment did to me. You've made my day! I'm done with this guy.......................zzzzzzz.....................

Comment: @Joseph: Thank you very much, This really is an insoluble problem?

Comment: It is not insoluble, but is not a problem of PHP or CI. It is about MySQL. The search engine is your friend, [check this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431053/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-ranks-in-mysql).