# problem with pagination?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

i use of codeigniter

Why not work `$this->pagination->create_links()` in my code?
**Problem 1:** I have this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: offset

Filename: admin/accommodation.php

Line Number: 45
```

**Problem 2:** After click on `$this->pagination->create_links()`, **change url**, but **does not change content table**.i use of XAMPP

**What do i do?**

my code:

```
function show() 
    {       
        // load pagination class
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/accommodation/show';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('hotel_submits');
    $config['per_page'] = '2';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $offset = (int) $offset; // just to make sure nothing funky gets in here
    $data['results'] = $this->db->query("SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.* ".
        "FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, hotel_submits t ".
        "ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $offset, 2");

        $this->load->view('admin/accommodation_submit_show', $data);   
    }
```

With respect

Comment: What does `$config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/accommodation/show';` mean? What's the name of your controller?

Comment: Where do you get `$offset` from? `$offset = (int) $offset;` refers to a non-available variable (right side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$offset` that you're using in your query in undefined. You have to pass it in as a method parameter, or use `$this->uri->segment(n)`.

Have you read my answer on [create jquery pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056223/create-jquery-pagination)

You have to pass $offset to your method:

```
function show($offset = 0) 
{
    // code goes here
}
```

I'll assume you have an installation of Codeigniter in a folder called "admin", and your controller's name is "accommodation". In that case you have to set `$config['base_url']` like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'accommodation/show';
```

**EDIT:**

If *admin* is not the folder you've installed Codeigniter in, but rather a folder inside your *controllers* folder which has the *accommodation* controller in it, then you'll have to use this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'admin/accommodation/show';
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

Comment: I think you have an error there regarding `$config['base_url']`, OP's `$config['base_url']` is already correct (although `base_url()` is not needed). You definitely need the `admin` segment though. Not sure what jquery has to do with this.  +1 for the `$offset` part and -1 for the rest.

Comment: @Wesley: If he has Codeigniter set up properly (which I assumed he did, maybe I'm wrong), his base_url in the config file should include the "admin" part of his url: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://hissite.com/admin'`. As for jQuery: if you'll look at that question, you'll see he copied all the code from my answer, but then messed it up. That's why I asked if he read it, because I think I've explained it there thoroughly enough...

Comment: OK, I see what you assumed with the `$config['base_url']`, although it is likely that OP is using a route or subdirectory within `/controllers` for the `/admin` part rather than having the entire installation be within an `admin` directory. It's kind of sad that people can't be bothered to read the error messages that PHP or CI are spitting out, or don't bother to learn what "Undefined variable" means. Defining the offset may be the only issue. Either way, it should have been resolved before asking the question.

Comment: Oh yeah I see it now: that's weird that OP copy/pasted code from the other question. Unless they are the same user, it makes no sense at all.